# Do you prefix every e-mail in a chain with a greeting?

Tags: politeness, email

Clearly, norms on etiquette dictates that you should prefix an e-mail to someone with "Dear Alice" or "Hi Alice" or something. But when engaging in an e-mail conversation chain, should I prefix EVERY message with a greeting? It feels kind of silly. Can I get away with skipping the greeting?

To elaborate, if an e-mail conversation has the purpose of emulating a 'real' conversation, then it seems that the repeated greetings would be skipped. That's what feels silly - a real conversation would involve ONE pair of greetings. If an e-mail conversation is meant to emulate an exchange of letters, then multiple greetings feels less arbitrary, but I feel that e-mail has more in common with a conversation than it has with sending letters.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you feel it kind of silly? This question will be regarded as "opinion-based" unless you are more specific.

Comment: Email is still a relatively new medium, and there is enormous variation in how people use it. On an almost daily basis I'll receive some emails that are only two or three words long, and others formatted like a formal block letter— down to the indentation of the physical mailing address to the top right. There isn't a single canonical answer we can give, as it depends on the tone of the chain, on the recipients and their relationship to one another, on the subject of the message, and so on. Skip the greetings if you feel they're silly; you have only your correspondents to answer to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will depend on the nature of the relationship between the correspondents, the nature of the conversation, and the culture in which it takes place.

When dealing with a customer it's probably best to use a greeting every time. Similarly when exchanging letter-like emails with someone fitting the "elderly relative" stereotype. In the case of a chain of short emails between colleagues, the sort of thing that could equally take place over an instant messenger system, of course not (in a western, informal workplace). Most cases will lie somewhere in between.

Unless you know the recipient well, it's probably best to start by erring on the side of formality, then allowing the nature and likelihood of greetings to reduce.